# Multiple Inheritance Python __init__ not working

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have these 2 classes:

```
from avatar import Avatar    
class Caster(Avatar):
    def __init__(self, name, life, strength, protection, mana):
        super().__init__(name, life, strength, protection)
        self._mana = mana
```

and:

```
from avatar import Avatar
class Melee(Avatar):
    def __init__(self, name, life, strength, protection, shield):
        super().__init__(name, life, strength, protection)
        self._shield = shield
```

Both of them inherit from:

```
class Avatar:
    def __init__(self, name, life, strength, protection):
        self._name = name
        self._life = life
        self._strength = strength
        self._protection = protection
```

Now I want to create a new class which inherits from both Caster and Melee

```
from melee import Melee
from caster import Caster
class Chaman(Melee, Caster):         
    def __init__(self, name, life, strength, protection, shield, mana):    
        Melee().__init__(self, name, life, strength, protection, shield)
        Caster().__init__(self, mana)
```

This new class combines elements from Melee and Caster. When I execute this and try to create new Chaman objects, it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'name', 'life', 'strength', 'protection', and 'shield'
```

Comment: You defined `Caster.__init__` to take all these arguments, but when you call `Caster().__init__` in `Chaman.__init__`  you don't provide them. Also `Caster()` already implicitly calls `Caster.__init__` (with no arguments at all), so you meant `Caster.__init__(...)`.

Comment: Don't mix ``super`` with explicit base class references. ``Chaman.__init__`` should just call ``super().__init__(name, life, strength, protection, shield)`` and let the base classes figure things out. You might have to swap the base classes, though.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have deleted this lines from Chaman.__init__:

Melee().__init__(self, name, life, strength, protection, shield)
Caster().__init__(self, mana)

Now the error it gives is:
__init__() takes 6 positional arguments but 7 were given

Which changes do you mean that I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design your classes and use `super` *correctly*, as discussed in further detail at [Python's `super()` considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

```
class Avatar:
    def __init__(self, *, name, life, strength, protection, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._name = name
        self._life = life
        self._strength = strength
        self._protection = protection


class Caster(Avatar):
    def __init__(self, *, mana, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._mana = mana


class Melee(Avatar):
    def __init__(self, *, shield, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._shield = shield


class Chaman(Melee, Caster):
    pass


# Note that the order of the *keyword* arguments does not matter.
c = Chaman(name="bob", life=3, strength=10, protection=5, mana=9, shield=0)
```

Each class only deals with the arguments it introduces, passing any others up the stack via `super`.

Since `Chaman.__init__` isn't defined, `Melee.__init__` will be called first; it will call `Caster.__init__` (*not* `Avatar.__init__`), which will call `Avatar.__init__`, which will call `object.__init__`, which will do nothing.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my incompetence, I am new at this. I have written the code as you say and now it looks like yours; the class Chaman now does not have '__init__ 'defined by me, I understand it inherits it from the other two classes. The problem is that it gives me the error "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mana'" when I try to create new objects.
As long as I understand this is because in "melee" there is no atribute "mana" while in "caster" there is, but for some reason, Python is not checking atributes of Caster. Thank you again.

Comment: The code above does not produce that error. You may have forgotten to add `**kwargs` to the signature of `Melee.__init__` or `Avatar.__init__`.